# How to properly Webpack library export?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, bundle, babeljs

First real foray into using webpack, and I'm trying to create a reusable library. I can't figure out how to properly export my library classes. Here's a general rundown of what I'm currently doing, and how I'm trying to use what's been built.

I have an entry point like so:

```
import ClassA from './classA';
import ClassB from './classB';

export {ClassA, ClassB};
```

That I would like to use the built library to import my classes when needed in my application:

```
import {ClassA} from './libs/library.js'; // currently using chrome flags for testing
```

But I can not figure out the right 'output' configuration for my webpack build. I'm using babel-env with a .babelrc like:

```
{
  "presets": [[
    "env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "last 2 versions"
      }
    }
  ]]
}
```

and a webpack config like:

```
const path = require('path');

export default () => ({
    entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './libs'),
        filename: 'library.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: ''
    },
    externals: {},
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "eslint-loader"
            }
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve('./node_modules'), path.resolve('./src')],
        extensions: ['.json', '.js']
    }
});
```

But, when trying to use my classes, via the import shown earlier, I get an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export
>   named 'ClassA'

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm sure I'm just missing the right configuration of webpack options, but hours of Google have not helped.

Comment: Try `export default`  instead of your present `export`

Comment: Where I'm trying to make multiple classes available from my module, I'm not sure how `export default` would help me?...

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a long-standing [feature request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2933) in Webpack to resolve this.

In the meantime, you may be able to do a simple `import './classA'`, which should add the variables to the global scope (this is the default behaviour of the `libraryTarget: 'umd'` option)